# Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::$dated (export excel using maatwebsite)

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, maatwebsite-excel

i got error and i don't know what the error is this

**in my controller**

```
 public function exportExcel(Request $data)
    {
        return Excel::download(new VgetAttGeneralExport($data), 'rekap-perkelas.xlsx');
    }
```

**here's my request**

```
0:{keyid: 6046, att_seq: 6046, att_enumber: "101415287", att_method: null, att_workcode: null,…}
```

**in my export folder**

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class VgetAttGeneralExport implements FromView
{
    use Exportable;


    public $data;
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
     public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        $data = $this->data;

        return view('exports.Kehadiran',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

**and this my view**

```
 <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($data as $item)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->dated }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->employee_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->employee_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->tingkat }}{{$item->div_name}}{{$item->kelas}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->stat_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->stat_desc }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

i've tried many way and i got stuck, anyone please help me, i'am very beginner in api laravel

Comment: I think `<td>{{ $item->dated }}</td>` should be `<td>{{ $item->date }}</td>`. Please check your property name.

Comment: Check Your `database field name` ,`fillable` Collection

Comment: @DhananjayKyada the name of property is correct